# How to cancel file upload in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have a post method

```
uploadFile: async function () {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", this.file);
  let url = `http://...`;
  try {
    this.source = axios.CancelToken.source();
    const res = await axios.post(url, formData, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Token " + this.$store.getters.getToken,
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
      cancelToken: this.source.token,
    });
  } catch (error) {
  }
}
```

and cancel method

```
  cancelLoad: function () {
      this.source.cancel('cancel upload');
  },
```

The request was canceled, but after reloading my page, the file uploaded.
[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the file loaded"?

Comment: @tony19 the file was uploaded and I can get it from the backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed it.

```
const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
let cancel;

const res = await axios.post(url, formData, {
      headers: {...},
      cancelToken: new CancelToken(function executor(c) {
        cancel = c;
      }),
}...

cancel();
```